# Windows CMD: Get relative path from absolute path

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd, relative-path, symlink

How do i obtain the relative path from an absolute path, e.g. convert 'C:\absolute\path\file.ext' to 'path'?

Thanks for your consideration

edit: i'd like to recursivly scan a directory for a certain filetype and then create symlinks for these folders containing this filetype. the symlinks should be named like the directory containing the filetype.

Comment: can you use external utilities like gnuwin utilities in your batch file?

Comment: i surely could but if possibly i'd stick to built-in routines as far as possible. shouldn't be a huge problem with grep then, i guess?

Comment: What precisely is the "relative" path? Because `absolute\name` seems to be an equally valid result. It's the path relative to the root directory, while `path` is the path relative to `C:\absolute\`. Or did you mean the name of the parent directory?

Comment: in fact, i need to get the directory, which actually contains the file, e.g. 'path' contains file.ext. i just need this one directory cropped from the rest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This function works
[DosTips.com :MakeRelative](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.MakeRelative)

It compares both pathes and removes the identical front.
Then it adds "..\" for each non matching part.

Comment: I'm always amazed at the fact that in Batch even the simplest programming task that goes beyond just launching a bunch of executables boils down to a series of incomprehensible for cycles. :S (+1, BTW)

Comment: looks pretty complicated, guess it'll work then ;)    how can i use this function in my batchfile? is it just a copy&paste and then just calling it?

Comment: @DapperDan: Yes, copy&paste is the style of such "Function Library", including is much more complicated