# Resolving a relative path without referencing the current directory on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, path, relative-path, msdn

I have a windows cpp app and I want to resolve paths relative to a specific directory without changing the current directory. This means I can't use `GetFullPathName` since it resolves paths relative to the current directory. Since this is a security sensitive issue I would rather not roll my own but use a sanctioned API.

I looked around for a good answer, but couldn't find anything. Surely this is a common issue for web servers or multithreaded environments. How do other people do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For instance: You run your app from `C:\appfolder\exes\myapp.exe` while the data is in `C:\appfolder\data`. I want to resolve `sillyfolder\..\mydata.txt` to `C:\appfolder\data\mydata.txt`.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: I don't think there is an API for this.  I believe the usual approach would be to just append the two parts together (with a backslash, obviously) and leave the path in non-canonical form.  If you know the file exists, I suppose you could open it and then call GetFinalPathNameByHandle.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, after concatenating the absolute base directory and the relative directory, why not call `GetFullPathName` to remove any `"."` and `".."` path components? `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` is useful if you need to resolve symbolic links in the full path, but you may have to iterate back to a path component that can be opened and then append the rest of the path that can't be accessed (either it doesn't exist or you have no access).

Comment: @eryksun: the documentation for `GetFullPathName` doesn't say what (if anything) it does if you pass it an absolute path.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, the docs are lacking, e.g. they don't discuss how `L"con"` becomes `L"\\\\.\\con"`, or using (and verifying) environment variables such as `"=D:"` for drive relative paths. ReactOS reverse engineers some of this in [`RtlGetFullPathName_UstrEx`](http://code.reactos.org/browse/~br=trunk/reactos/trunk/reactos/lib/rtl/path.c?r=65535#to1947) and [`RtlGetFullPathName_Ustr`](http://code.reactos.org/browse/~br=trunk/reactos/trunk/reactos/lib/rtl/path.c?r=65535#to468). FWIW, the documentation does give 3 examples: `\\test-2\q$\lh`, `\\?\UNC\test-2\q$\lh`, and `U:`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The standard (C++ or Win32) libraries do not do this for you, it seems.  But making a relative path is a good exercise.  Here are a few useful links to see how to start (treat scripts as *pseudocode*):

- [Converting an absolute path to a relative path](http://lessons.runrev.com/m/2592/l/126010-converting-an-absolute-path-to-a-relative-path)
- [Windows CMD: Get relative path from absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816541/windows-cmd-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path)
- [MakeRelative - makes a file name relative to a base path](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.MakeRelative)

Converting an absolute pathname to relative requires

- the given *target* path which should be converted
- a path which is the *current* directory.

The conversion would be done as a string-manipulation:

- start by finding the longest common prefix which ends with a path-separator.
- if there is no common prefix, you are done
- strip the common prefix from (a copy of...) the current and target strings
- replace each directory-name in the *current* string with ".."
- add that (with a path-separator) in front of the target string
- return that combined string

Unlike Unix pathnames (aside from the sense of "/" versus "\" for separators), Windows pathnames have additional complications:

- within the same machine, they can have device names (a letter followed by a ":")
- [UNC pathnames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx), which begin with "\".

For the latter case (UNC paths), if the *current* and *target* paths are not on the same host, then relative paths are meaningless.  However, device names and pathnames are not that tightly bound together (note that Windows added the ability to change devices with chdir later, as an [option](https://superuser.com/questions/225692/why-is-cd-in-windows-not-able-to-switch-between-drives)), and depending on the application one could make relative pathnames between devices by considering only the path part.

Comment: The OP wants to convert a relative path to an absolute path, not the other way around.

Comment: The first link should be useful then. The point is that there likely is no standard call, and that by looking at others' work, OP may learn how to do this.